# Creating a wrapper in Python which uses another wrapper

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wrapper

I have a problem with creating a wrapper in Python. My wrapper needs to check if the user has a token, and if it doesn't - call another wrapper which can also be used separately. Here is my code:

```
import functools

def require_domain_or_token(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_has_token, dd, user_draft= Security.get_user_token(self.request)
        if user_has_token:
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return require_domain(method)
    return wrapper


def require_domain(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = Security.get_current_logged_in_user()
        if not user:
            logging.info("No user detected. Redirecting")
            return self.redirect(login_url(dest_url = self.request.path_qs))

            ......

        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

If the user has a token it works, but if not it throws an exception:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'redirect'
```

I know I didn't call `require_domain(method)` correctly because I didn't pass  `self, *args, **kwargs` to method. How do I use `require_domain` from `require_domain_or_token`?

We are using Google App Engine (but I'm not sure if it matters).

**Update:** I invoked the method according to the answer, but I moved the `return` to the end of the function:

```
def require_domain_or_token(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_has_token, dd, user_draft= Security.get_user_token(self.request)
        if user_has_token:
            returned_method = method
        else:
            returned_method = require_domain(method)
        return returned_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorator `require_domain` also returns wrapper (function), so you need to invoke it:

```
return require_domain(method)(self, *args, **kwargs)
```